# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument error with simple server class

Tags: python, sockets

I'm having problems with this very very simple server class, used to run something very similar to this a couple of weeks ago and it worked fine, now i'm getting this error:

```
root@kali:/tmp# python3 server.py                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 38, in <module>
    accept_conns()
  File "server.py", line 24, in accept_conns
    conn, addr = s.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 212, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Code:

```
import socket
import os

def create_socket():
    global s
    try:
        s = socket.socket()

    except socket.error as create_err:
        print(create_err)


def bind_socket():
    global s
    try:
        s.bind(("192.168.0.120", 4444))

    except socket.error as bind_err:
        print(bind_err)


def accept_conns():
    global s
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: " + addr)

    while True:
        comm = input("shell> ")
        if comm is 'quit':
            break
        conn.send(comm.encode())
        output = conn.recv(2048)
        print(output)


create_socket()
bind_socket()
accept_conns()
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

```
import socket
import os

def create_socket():
    s = socket.socket()
    return s

def bind_socket(s):
    s.bind(("192.168.0.120", 4444))

def accept_conns(s):
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: ", addr)

    while True:
        comm = input("shell> ")
        if comm is 'quit':
            break
        conn.send(comm.encode())
        output = conn.recv(2048)
        print(output)

s = create_socket()
bind_socket(s)
accept_conns(s)
```